# Unable to copy files from Windows partition into Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, nautilus, lubuntu

I'm running Lubunto OS right now, navigated to the Windows 7 partition using the file manager, navigated further into the wallpaper folder in the Windows partition, copied a wallpaper file.

Next, I navigated to

```
/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers
```

then paste, but I get this message:

```
The file operation was completed with errors.
```

And the file wasn't copied at all.

What should I do? Please help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have permission to add or change files in /usr/share/ - it is owned by root.

To change this, you can either run your file manager as root which will give you full permissions on any folder you want (not ideal, can be dangerous), or alternatively you can use the command

```
sudo cp /change/this/path/to/windows/wallpapers/* /usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/*
```

If you *really* need to do this with your file manager, use the command

```
sudo pcmanfm
```

and your file manager will gain root access. Please, watch what you're doing. You will have the ability to remove or alter core system files if you're not careful.

Comment: That's great Drac.  It seems to be only temporary though; as soon as I close the file manager, the permission is gone.  So...how do I make this last for as long as my computer is on, and how do I create a desktop shortcut so that when I turn on my computer, all I have to do is click on the icon on my desktop and the file manager would automatically be rooted? Thank you

Comment: @Kaye, Running file manager or any other application every time with root privilege is risky and not recommended. Run an application with `sudo` only if it is required.

Comment: @Kaye - g_p is right. Having easy access to a root file manager is going to lead to trouble. If you need it in the future, use the "sudo pcmanfm" command in a terminal so it's not so easily accessible.